# Set a border around expanded row

Tags: c#, winforms, devexpress, xtragrid

I'm using a devexpress xtragrid (C# winforms) with events to dynamically bind master rows to detail rows. When I expand a master row, I'm looking to set a border around the master and detail row. When a master row is expanded, I want a blue frame around the row together with its detail rows to make it stand out to the user.

Answer (score 0):

You can accomplish your task with using the approach, based on handling the `GridControl.Paint` event:

```
gridControl1.DataSource = Repository.GetOrders();
// Some Visual Options for details
gridView1.LevelIndent = 0;
gridView1.OptionsDetail.ShowDetailTabs = false;
gridView1.OptionsDetail.AllowOnlyOneMasterRowExpanded = true;
// 
gridControl1.Paint += gridControl1_Paint;
//...
void gridControl1_Paint(object sender, PaintEventArgs e) {
    var viewInfo = gridView1.GetViewInfo() as GridViewInfo;
    foreach(var rowInfo in viewInfo.RowsInfo) {
        if(gridView1.GetMasterRowExpanded(rowInfo.RowHandle))
            e.Graphics.DrawRectangle(Pens.Blue, rowInfo.TotalBounds);
    }
}
```

Data classes:

```
public static class Repository {
    public static List<Order> GetOrders() {
        return new List<Order> { 
            new Order(){ Id=0, Date = DateTime.Now.AddDays(-1), 
                Items = new List<OrderItem>{
                    new OrderItem(){ Id=0, Name="A"},
                    new OrderItem(){ Id=1, Name="B"},
                }
            },
            new Order(){ Id=1, Date = DateTime.Now, 
                Items = new List<OrderItem>{
                    new OrderItem(){ Id=0, Name="A"},
                    new OrderItem(){ Id=1, Name="B"},
                    new OrderItem(){ Id=1, Name="C"},
                }
            }
        };
    }
}
public class Order {
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public DateTime Date { get; set; }
    public List<OrderItem> Items { get; set; }
}
public class OrderItem {
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```